# Form won't submit when an inner html is updated

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am creating a webpage that has search, add, update, and delete (all in one webpage without any modals). This webpage is dedicated for facility maintenance. Add works fine. But the rest doesn't look good. Whenever I add a 'facility', the page reloads (as expected). The page gets the data from mysql database and add it on a table inside my webpage. The table has a column called 'Actions' that holds two buttons, `update` and `delete`.

The problem is when I use innerHTML. On the top of the table containing the list of 'facilities', is a search input. Search works fine (I think). Search uses the 'POST' method and accesses a PHP code inside my file. The PHP code is tasked to search for any matching strings from the database and echo `<script> </script>`. Inside these script tags is a code where I searched for the id of the table I want to update. Then I changed & added inner HTML. Inside the inner HTML is a new table row. Inside the table row is a form, and inside these forms are `<td>`s. Whenever the form(the form inside each table rows) submits, it should access a PHP code inside my file that has already been written (it was already there when the page first loads). But whenever I click the action buttons on my table, it does nothing. It doesn't trigger the PHP POST code written.

Clicking `update` and `delete` buttons works fine IF search is not clicked first. Clicking `update` will create another table with input fields and a button to save changes. The 'button-to-save-changes' doesn't work even if it has a PHP POST code already written in the file.

Here is my code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Facilities</title>
        <?php
            include_once("connection.php");
            include_once("pktool-v1.0.php");
        ?>

    </head>

    <body>
        <h1><center>Facilities</center></h1>
        <br>
        <br>
        <div id="addfac">
        <p>Add Facility</p>
        <hr>
            <form method="post" action="facilities.php">
                <br>
                <label name="naFacName">Facility Name: </label>
                <input type="input" name="inputFacName"><br><br>
                <label name="naFacType">Facility Type: </label>
                <select name="naFacSel">
                    <?php
                        $query = "SELECT * FROM tblFacType WHERE " . 
                                                "boolArchive = FALSE;";
                        $array_fetch = mysqli_query($con, $query);

                        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($array_fetch)) {
                            $value_added = $row[0];
                            $value_text = $row[1];
                            echo "<option name='naFacType' value='$value_added'>$value_text</option>    ";
                        }
                    ?>
                </select>
                <br><br>
                <label name="naFacAdd">Facility Address: </label>
                <input type="input" name="lot" placeholder="Lot No. or Block">
                <input type="input" name="street" placeholder="Street">
                <input type="input" name="brgy" placeholder="Barangay"><br><br>
                <input type="input" name="city" placeholder="City">
                <input type="input" name="province" placeholder="Province">
                <input type="input" name="region" placeholder="Region">
                <br><br>
                <label name="naFacAddType">Facility Address Type: </label>
                <?php
                    $query = "SELECT * FROM tblAddType WHERE strAddTypeDesc = 'Facility Address' " .
                                                        "AND boolArchive = FALSE;";
                    $array_fetch = mysqli_query($con, $query);
                    //echo "<br> ERROR IS: " . mysqli_error($con) . " <br>";
                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($array_fetch)) {
                        $row_val = $row[0];
                        echo "<label value='$row_val'>$row[1]</label>";
                        echo "<input type='hidden' name='naAddType' value='$row_val'>";
                    }
                ?>
                <br><br>
                <label name="naFacValue">Facility Value (Day): </label>
                <input type="input" name="inputFacValue"><br><br>
                <label name="naFacValueNight">Facility Value (Night): </label>
                <input type="input" name="inputFacValueNight">
                <br><br>
                <center><input type="submit" name="Submit_Facility"></center>
            </form>

            <?php
                if(isset($_POST['Submit_Facility'])) 
                {
                    $add_pk = PrimaryKey::prependPK(PrimaryKey::generatePK(), "ADD-");
                    $queryStat = true;

                    $lot = $_POST['lot'];
                    $street = $_POST['street'];
                    $brgy = $_POST['brgy'];
                    $city = $_POST['city'];
                    $province = $_POST['province'];
                    $region = $_POST['region'];

                    $fac_name = $_POST['inputFacName'];
                    $fac_val = $_POST['inputFacValue'];
                    $fac_val_night = $_POST['inputFacValueNight'];
                    $fac_type = $_POST['naFacSel'];
                    $add_type = $_POST['naAddType'];

                    $query = "INSERT INTO " . 
                                "tblAddress(strAddID, strRegion, strProvince, strCity, strBarangay, " .  
                                            "strStreet, strLot, intAddTypeID) " . 
                                "VALUES('$add_pk', '$lot', '$street', '$brgy', '$city', '$province', " . 
                                        "'$region', '$add_type');";
                    if (!mysqli_query($con, $query)) {
                        $queryStat = false;
                    }

                    $facloc_pk = PrimaryKey::prependPK(PrimaryKey::generatePK(), "FACLOC-");
                    $fac_pk = PrimaryKey::prependPK(PrimaryKey::generatePK(), "FAC-");

                    $query = "INSERT INTO " . 
                                "tblFacility(strFacID, strFacName, intFacTypeID, dblFacValDay, dblFacValNight) " . 
                                "VALUES('$fac_pk', '$fac_name', $fac_type, $fac_val, $fac_val_night);";

                    if(!mysqli_query($con, $query)) {
                        $queryStat = false;
                    }

                    $query = "INSERT INTO " . 
                                "tblFacLoc(strFacLocID, strFacID, strAddID) " . 
                                "VALUES('$facloc_pk', '$fac_pk', '$add_pk');";

                    if(!mysqli_query($con, $query)) {
                        $queryStat = false;
                    }

                    if ($queryStat) {
                        echo "<script>alert('Successfully Added!');</script>";
                    } else {
                        $alert_msg = "Error! " . mysqli_error($con);
                        echo "<script>alert('$alert_msg');</script>";
                    }

                }
            ?>
        </div>
        <br>
        <hr>
        <h3><center>All Facilities</center></h3>
        <div>
            <form method='POST' style='text-align:right'>
                <label name='naSearch'>Search:</label>
                <input type='text' name='s_keyword' placeholder='Enter a keyword'>
                <input type='submit' value='Search' name='btnSubmit'>
                <br><br>
            </form>
            <br>

            <table id='tblFacilities'>
                <tr>
                    <th>Facility ID</th>
                    <th>Facility Name</th>
                    <th>Facility Rental Price (Day)</th>
                    <th>Facility Rental Price (Night)</th>
                    <th>Facility Type</th>
                    <th>Facility Location</th>
                    <th colspan=2>Actions</th>
                </tr>

                <?php
                    $query = "SELECT a.strFacID, a.strFacName, a.dblFacValDay, a.dblFacValNight, " . 
                                    "b.strFacTypeDesc, " . 
                                    "d.strUnit, d.strLot, d.strStreet, d.strBarangay, d.strCity, d.strProvince, " . 
                                    "d.strRegion " . 
                            "FROM tblFacility a, tblFacType b, tblFacLoc c, tblAddress d " . 
                            "WHERE a.intFacTypeID = b.intFacTypeID AND " . 
                                    "a.strFacID = c.strFacID AND " . 
                                    "c.strAddID = d.strAddID AND " . 
                                    "a.boolArchive = FALSE;";

                    $array_fetch = mysqli_query($con, $query);

                    while ($tuple = mysqli_fetch_array($array_fetch)) {
                        $fac_ID = $tuple[0];
                        $fac_name = $tuple[1];
                        $fac_val = $tuple[2];
                        $fac_val_night = $tuple[3];
                        $fac_type = $tuple[4];
                        $fac_add = $tuple[5] . " " . $tuple[6] . " " . $tuple[7] . " " . $tuple[8] . " " . 
                                        $tuple[9] . " " . $tuple[10] . " " . $tuple[11] . " ";

                        echo "<tr> " . 
                                "<form method='post' > " . 
                                    "<td><input type='hidden' name='fac_id' value='$fac_ID'>$fac_ID</td> " . 
                                    "<td><input type='hidden' name='fac_name' value='$fac_name'>$fac_name</td> " . 
                                    "<td><input type='hidden' name='fac_val' value='$fac_val'>$fac_val</td> " . 
                                    "<td><input type='hidden' name='fac_val_night' value='$fac_val_night'>$fac_val_night</td> " .
                                    "<td><input type='hidden' name='fac_type' value='$fac_type'>$fac_type</td> " .  
                                    "<td><input type='hidden' name='fac_add' value='$fac_add'>$fac_add</td> " . 
                                    "<td><input type='submit' name='naUpd' value='Update'></td> " . 
                                    "<td><input type='submit' name='naDel' value='Delete'></td> " . 
                                "</form> " . 
                            "</tr>";
                    }
                ?>

            </table>

            <br>
            <br>

            <div style="display: 'solid'">
                <table id="tblfaci">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Facility ID</th>
                        <th>Facility Name</th>
                        <th>Facility Rental Price (Day)</th>
                        <th>Facility Rental Price (Night)</th>
                        <th>Facility Type</th>
                        <th colspan=7>Facility Location</th>
                        <th>Action</th>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>

            <?php
                if (isset($_GET['btnSubmit'])) {
                    $keyword_q = $_GET['s_keyword'];
                    $query = "SELECT a.strFacID, a.strFacName, a.dblFacValDay, a.dblFacValNight, " . 
                                    "b.strFacTypeDesc, " . 
                                    "d.strUnit, d.strLot, d.strStreet, d.strBarangay, d.strCity, d.strProvince, " . 
                                    "d.strRegion " . 
                            "FROM tblFacility a, tblFacType b, tblFacLoc c, tblAddress d " . 
                            "WHERE a.intFacTypeID = b.intFacTypeID AND " . 
                                    "a.strFacID = c.strFacID AND " . 
                                    "c.strAddID = d.strAddID AND " . 
                                    "a.boolArchive = FALSE AND (" .
                                        "a.strFacID LIKE '%$keyword_q%' OR " . 
                                        "a.strFacName LIKE '%$keyword_q%' OR " .  
                                        "b.strFacTypeDesc LIKE '%$keyword_q%' OR " . 
                                        "d.strUnit LIKE '%$keyword_q%' OR " . 
                                        "d.strLot LIKE '%$keyword_q%' OR " . 
                                        "d.strStreet LIKE '%$keyword_q%' OR " . 
                                        "d.strBarangay LIKE '%$keyword_q%' OR " . 
                                        "d.strCity LIKE '%$keyword_q%' OR " . 
                                        "d.strProvince LIKE '%$keyword_q%' OR " . 
                                        "a.dblFacValDay = " . (int)$keyword_q . " OR " . 
                                        "a.dblFacValNight = " . (int)$keyword_q . " OR " . 
                                        "d.strRegion LIKE '%$keyword_q%'" . 
                                    ");";

                    $array_fetch = mysqli_query($con, $query);

                    echo "<script>" . 
                            "var tblFac = document.getElementById('tblFacilities'); " .
                            "tblFac.innerHTML = \"<tr> " .
                                            "<th>Facility ID</th> " .
                                                    "<th>Facility Name</th> " . 
                                                "<th>Facility Rental Price (Day)</th> " .
                                                "<th>Facility Rental Price (Night)</th> " .
                                                "<th>Facility Type</th> " .
                                                "<th>Facility Location</th> " .
                                                "<th colspan=2>Actions</th> " .
                                            "</tr>\";" . 
                         "</script>"; 

                    while ($tuple = mysqli_fetch_array($array_fetch)) {
                        $fac_ID = $tuple[0];
                        $fac_name = $tuple[1];
                        $fac_val = $tuple[2];
                        $fac_val_night = $tuple[3];
                        $fac_type = $tuple[4];
                        $fac_add = $tuple[5] . " " . $tuple[6] . " " . $tuple[7] . " " . $tuple[8] . " " . 
                                        $tuple[9] . " " . $tuple[10] . " " . $tuple[11] . " ";


                        echo "<script>" . 
                                "var tblFac = document.getElementById('tblFacilities'); " .
                                "tblFac.innerHTML += \"" . 
                                 "<tr> " . 
                                     "<form method='post' > " . 
                                        "<td><input type='hidden' name='fac_id' value='$fac_ID'>$fac_ID</td> " . 
                                        "<td><input type='hidden' name='fac_name' value='$fac_name'>$fac_name</td> " . 
                                        "<td><input type='hidden' name='fac_val' value='$fac_val'>$fac_val</td> " . 
                                        "<td><input type='hidden' name='fac_val_night' value='$fac_val_night'>$fac_val_night</td> " .
                                        "<td><input type='hidden' name='fac_type' value='$fac_type'>$fac_type</td> " . 
                                        "<td><input type='hidden' name='fac_add' value='$fac_add'>$fac_add</td> " . 
                                        "<td><input type='submit' name='naUpd' value='Update'></td> " . 
                                        "<td><input type='submit' name='naDel' value='Delete'></td " . 
                                     "</form> " . 
                                 "</tr>\";" . 
                             "</script>";
                    }
                }
            ?>

            <?php
                if (isset($_POST['naUpd'])) {
                    echo "<script>alert('UPDATE');</script>";
                    $id = $_POST['fac_id'];
                    $name = $_POST['fac_name'];
                    $val = $_POST['fac_val'];
                    $val_n = $_POST['fac_val_night'];
                    $type = $_POST['fac_type'];

                    $query = "SELECT a.strFacID, a.strFacName, a.dblFacValDay, a.dblFacValNight, " . 
                                    "b.strFacTypeDesc, " . 
                                    "d.strUnit, d.strLot, d.strStreet, d.strBarangay, d.strCity, d.strProvince, " . 
                                    "d.strRegion " . 
                            "FROM tblFacility a, tblFacType b, tblFacLoc c, tblAddress d " . 
                            "WHERE a.intFacTypeID = b.intFacTypeID AND " . 
                                    "a.strFacID = c.strFacID AND " . 
                                    "c.strAddID = d.strAddID AND " . 
                                    "a.boolArchive = FALSE AND " . 
                                    "a.strFacID = '$id';";

                    $array_fetch = mysqli_query($con, $query); 

                    while ($tuple = mysqli_fetch_array($array_fetch)) {
                        $lot = $tuple[5];
                        $street = $tuple[6];
                        $unit = $tuple[7];
                        $barangay = $tuple[8];
                        $city = $tuple[9];
                        $province = $tuple[10];
                        $region = $tuple[11];

                        $innerCode = "<script>".
                                "var tblfaci = document.getElementById('tblfaci'); " .
                                "tblfaci.innerHTML += \"" .
                                "<tr><form method='post' action='facilities.php'> ".
                                "<td><input type='text' name = 'upd_fac_id' value = '$id' readonly></td> ".
                                "<td><input type='text' name = 'upd_fac_name' value = '$name'></td> ".
                                "<td><input type='text' name = 'upd_fac_val' value = '$val'></td> ".
                                "<td><input type='text' name = 'upd_fac_val_night' value = '$val_n'></td> ";

                        $innerCode .= "<td> ";
                            $innerCode .= "<select name='updFacType'>";

                                $query2 = "SELECT * FROM tblFacType WHERE " . 
                                                "boolArchive = FALSE;";
                                $array_fetch = mysqli_query($con, $query2);

                                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($array_fetch)) {
                                    $value_added = $row[0];
                                    $value_text = $row[1];
                                    $innerCode .= "<option name='naUpdFacType' value='$value_added'>$value_text</option>";
                                }

                            $innerCode .= "</select>";
                        $innerCode .= "</td>";      

                        $innerCode .= "<td><input type='text' name = 'upd_lot' value = '$lot'></td>".
                                "<td><input type='text' name = 'upd_street' value = '$street'></td>".
                                "<td><input type='text' name = 'upd_unit' value = '$unit'></td>".
                                "<td><input type='text' name = 'upd_barangay' value = '$barangay'></td>".
                                "<td><input type='text' name = 'upd_city' value = '$city'></td>".
                                "<td><input type='text' name = 'upd_province' value = '$province'></td>".
                                "<td><input type='text' name = 'upd_region' value = '$region'></td>".
                                "<td><input type='submit' value = 'Save' name = 'btnSaveUpdate'>".
                                "</form></tr>\";".
                            "</script>";

                        echo $innerCode;
                    }
                }
                if (isset($_POST['naDel'])) {
                    $del_pk = $_POST['fac_id'];

                    $query = "UPDATE tblFacility a, tblFacLoc b, tblAddress c " . 
                                "SET a.boolArchive = TRUE, b.boolArchive = TRUE, c.boolArchive = TRUE " . 
                                "WHERE a.strFacID = b.strFacID AND " . 
                                        "c.strAddID = b.strAddID AND " . 
                                        "a.strFacID = '$del_pk';";

                    if(!mysqli_query($con, $query)) {
                        $alert_msg = "Error! " . mysqli_error($con);
                        echo "<script>alert('$alert_msg');</script>";
                    } else {
                        echo "<script>alert('Successfully Removed!');</script>";
                    }

                    header("Location: facilities.php");
                }

            ?>

            <?php
                if (isset($_POST['btnSaveUpdate'])) {

                    $pk_id = $_POST['upd_fac_id'];
                    $edit_fac_type = $_POST['updFacType'];
                    $upd_fac_name = $_POST['upd_fac_name'];

                    $upd_fac_val = $_POST[''];
                    $upd_fac_val_night = $_POST[''];

                    $upd_region = $_POST['upd_region'];
                    $upd_province = $_POST['upd_province'];
                    $upd_city = $_POST['upd_city'];
                    $upd_barangay = $_POST['upd_barangay'];
                    $upd_street = $_POST['upd_street'];
                    $upd_lot = $_POST['upd_lot'];


                    $query = "UPDATE tblFacility a, tblAddress b, tblFacLoc c " . 
                                "SET a.intFacTypeID = (SELECT intFacTypeID " . 
                                                        "FROM tblFacType " . 
                                                        "WHERE strFacTypeDesc = '$edit_fac_type'), " . 
                                    "a.strFacName = '$upd_fac_name', " . 
                                    "a.dblFacValDay = $upd_fac_val, " . 
                                    "a.dblFacValNight = $upd_fac_val_night, " . 
                                    "b.strRegion = '$upd_region', " . 
                                    "b.strProvince = '$upd_province', " . 
                                    "b.strCity = '$upd_city', " . 
                                    "b.strBarangay = '$upd_barangay', " . 
                                    "b.strStreet = '$upd_street', " . 
                                    "b.strLot = '$upd_lot' " . 
                                "WHERE a.strFacID = c.strFacID AND " .
                                    "c.strAddID = b.strAddID AND " .
                                    "a.strFacID = '$pk_id';";

                    if(!mysqli_query($con, $query)) {
                        $alert_msg = "Error! " . mysqli_error($con);
                        echo "<script>alert('$alert_msg');</script>";
                    } else {
                        echo "<script>alert('Successfully Updated!!');</script>";

                        header("Location: facilities.php");
                    }
                }
            ?>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I'm not sure if the innerHTML cannot find the PHP code fir it's post, or the POST cannot find the innerHTML, or anything. I noticed that whenever I used innerHTML and add forms with it, I think it won't submit the form. What should I do?

Comment: You're creating invalid HTML. You can't have `<form>` as a child of `<tr>`, the children of `<tr>` have to be `<td>` or `<th>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the nesting of your HTML elements is wrong, because you're putting `<form>` as a child of `<tr>`.

What you can do is put the whole form in a single `<tr>`. This will work OK because all the inputs are hidden inputs, so they don't have to be in separate `<td>`. The exceptions are the submit buttons, but it should look OK to have them together in the last column.

```
echo "<tr> " . 
        "<td>$fac_ID</td> " . 
        "<td>$fac_name</td> " . 
        "<td>$fac_val</td> " . 
        "<td>$fac_val_night</td> " .
        "<td>$fac_type</td> " .  
        "<td>$fac_add</td> " . 
        "<td><form method="post">" .
            "<input type='hidden' name='fac_id' value='$fac_ID'>" .
            "<input type='hidden' name='fac_name' value='$fac_name'>" .
            "<input type='hidden' name='fac_val' value='$fac_val'>" .
            "<input type='hidden' name='fac_val_night' value='$fac_val_night'>" .
            "<input type='hidden' name='fac_type' value='$fac_type'>" .
            "<input type='hidden' name='fac_add' value='$fac_add'>" .
            "<input type='submit' name='naUpd' value='Update'> " . 
            "<input type='submit' name='naDel' value='Delete'>" .
        "</form></td> " . 
    "</tr>";
```